# Clip raster geodata

Tags: python, inputmask

Подскажите, есть ли наиболее простой способ обрезать растровый слой в `python` с использованием шейп-файла?

Comment: Приведите небольшой пример входных и выходных данных

Comment: что у вас есть в арсенале? numpy, arcpy?

Comment: попробуйте задать вопрос на тематическом сегменте https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: В моем наборе модулей есть gdal,numpy,georaster,etc.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте (к сожалению без проверки):

```
import ogr
import subprocess

raster = r'raster.tif'
shp = r'my.shp'

ds = ogr.Open(shp)
lyr = ds.GetLayer(0)

lyr.ResetReading()
ft = lyr.GetNextFeature()

while ft:
    suffix_name = ft.GetFieldAsString('name')

    out_raster = raster.replace('.tif', '_%s.tif' % suffix_name.replace(' ', '_'))
    subprocess.call(['gdalwarp', raster, out_raster, '-cutline', shp,
                     '-crop_to_cutline', '-cwhere', "'name'='%s'" % suffix_name])

    ft = lyr.GetNextFeature()

ds = None
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, попробую

Answer (score 0):

спасибр всем за подсказку!
В итоге, вопрос решился с использованием модуля RasterIO:

```
import fiona
import rasterio
from rasterio.tools.mask import mask

with fiona.open("F:/SRB_Mosaic/003_Shapefiles/studyarea_0718_32642.shp", "r") as shapefile: 
    geoms = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile] 

with rasterio.open("F:/SRB_Mosaic/001_Initial_10m_images/Initial_data/T42TWM_20170525T061631_B03.jp2") as src: 
    out_image, out_transform = mask(src, geoms, crop=True) 
    out_meta = src.meta.copy() 

out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                 "height": out_image.shape[1],
                 "width": out_image.shape[2],
                 "transform": out_transform}) 

with rasterio.open("F:/T42TWM_20170525T061631_B03clip.tif", "w", **out_meta) as dest: 
    dest.write(out_image)
```

Загвоздка была в разной зоне проекции шейп-файла и растрового слоя. Сначала я привел их в одну зону, затем сумел применить маску векторного файла к растру. Удачи всем!